# BUILD FAILED in 18s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, gradle, task, emulation

When I try to execute a flutter project in Android Studios, the emulator appears but nothing happens. Adn the only message that appears in the program is: 
"BUILD FAILED in 18s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons why your build failed. I would start by trying `flutter clean`

If that doesn't help, provide us with more details about your app such as plugins or your `flutter doctor` so we can better answer your question!